# SyntaxError from "pip install quantecon"

Tags: python

everbody I'm having several troubles for install packages through pip. If I putin spyder this code

```
import pip
pip install quantecon
```

I receive

```
  **File "C:\Users\CESAR\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 710, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\CESAR\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 101, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/CESAR/Desktop/PYTHON/3.py", line 9
    pip install quantecon
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax**
```

In Thonny is same, I don't as solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

```
>>> %Run 2.py

  File "C:\Users\CESAR\Desktop\PYTHON\2.py", line 3
    pip install quantecon
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: `pip install quantecon` has to be in the Command Line

Comment: An ALL-CAPS TITLE reads as trying to privilege your question over others by making it louder -- it's not good etiquette.

Answer (score 0):

Press Win+R and enter `pip install quantecon` there. This isn't python code and will work only in command line/powershell/wsl/git bash